# What is the definition of the `projects` command in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

In SBT, we can type `projects` show the projects in a list, but it seems is not a normal task, because `inspect projects` or `show projects` will report:

```
Not a valid project ID: projects (similar: root)
```

What is the `projects` and how can I find the definition? I want to see the implementation of it to do some other work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a command, here the entry point of its [implementation](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13.8/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Main.scala#L404-L407).